# Preventing redirect when changing language in DataLife engine

Tags: multilingual, datalife-engine

I need help with DataLife Engine. I've created a website in three languages. However, when I'm on the contact page and change the language, I'm redirected to the main page. I want to stay on the same page when I change the language. I'm currently using these .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteRule ^eng/(/?)+$ index.php?action_skin_change=yes&skin_name=eng [L]
RewriteRule ^rus/(/?)+$ index.php?action_skin_change=yes&skin_name=rus [L]
RewriteRule ^geo/(/?)+$ index.php?action_skin_change=yes&skin_name=geo [L]
```

And this is the selector code:

```html
<div class="dropdown2 hidem" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".7">
    <button onclick="myFunction2()" class="dropbtn2">
        <img src="{THEME}/images/geo.png" alt="Georgian" />
        Georgian
    </button>
    <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown2-content">
        <a href="/en/">
            <img src="{THEME}/images/eng.png" alt="English" /> English
        </a>
        <a href="/ru/">
            <img src="{THEME}/images/rus.png" alt="Russian" /> Russian
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried changing the rules, but nothing seems to work. Can someone please help?